# BI Publisher - Fail to load and save data model

Tags: sql, datamodel, bi-publisher

Started BI Publisher about a week ago.
When working on a new data model, about one or two queries in, I get this error when I try to save:

```
Failed to load servlet/res?s=%252F~developer1%252Ftest%252FJustin%2520Tests%252FOSRP%2520Information.xdm&desc=&_sTkn=9ba70c01152efbcb413.
```

I can no longer save my data model.
I tried deleting my queries, logging in and out, turning machine off and on, but no luck.

I'm currently resolved to saving all of my queries locally in notepad.

I can create a whole new data model and it will save fine, but then after two or three queries the same thing happens.
What's going on and why would anyone design such a confusing error message?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After restarting your server once you won't get this issue.It happens some time due to the connection problem.so restart should work for this.It resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

None of the proposed solutions worked for me. I found out, on my own, that any unnecessary brackets around CASE in a select statement will cause this error. Remove the unnecessary brackets and the error goes away.

Answer (score -1):

Oracle meta link Doc ID `2173333.1`. In BI Publisher releases `11.1.1.8.x` and up, there is an option to *Manage Cache* in the Administration section of BIP. This option was also added to `11.1.1.7` in patch `140715` (`11.1.1.7.140715`).

Clearing the object cache will resolve the saving errors:

1. Click on the Administration link
2. Manage BI Publisher
3. Manage Cache
4. Click on the 'Clear Object Cache'